# How to resize a modern windows app with autohotkey

Tags: windows-8, resize, autohotkey

I've seen many scripts that resize windows applications, but none worked with modern apps. 
I'd think it would be really simple, but, somehow it doesn't recognize send or sendinput.
My problem case example is:

```
1 Launch app/document associated with a modern app,such as Reader
2 Use windows+left arrow to "dock" app to the side.
3 Launch another app/application
```

Comment: For Windows10 TP I've found a solution.

Comment: Do you have a sample? I could try it. Anyway, nice to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying out the tips in the comments, I debugged the error until I realize that `Left` was not being interpreted as the **Left Arrow** (*even though it says so in the help of AutoHotkey*).

**Replacing `Left` with `NumpadLeft` solved it.**

*No UIAccess needed in this case*.

Sample:

```
RunWait "D:\Temp\TranslationSource.pdf" ; opens Windows 8.1 Reader
Send #{NumpadLeft} ; docks it to the left
Send !{Tab} ; docks Desktop on the other half of the screen
RunWait "D:\Temp\TranslationTarget.txt" ; opens editor
Send #{NumpadUp} ; maximizes editor
; basic translation workspace setup done!
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need your script to have UIAccess

> A number of security changes have been implemented in Windows 8 which prevent programs which are not Metro apps from injecting keys that would remove you from the Metro environment. The way this works is that the keyboard shortcut is ignored if it doesn't come from a physical keyboard or a program that has the appropriate permissions. [...] In order to have the proper permissions, the program must be built with UIAccess (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742884.aspx).

[Forum topic](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/84771-alttab-mapping-isnt-working-anymore-in-windows-8/#entry548989)

Comment: I'll try that approach on the afternoon. Hope it works

Comment: No results. In fact, Alt+Tab (SendPlay !{Tab}) worked, but since I didn't try it before, I'm not sure it's because of the script or not. However, #Left / #{Left} (to "dock" left the app) didn't work. I used Send, SendInput and SendPlay.

Comment: Got it using #{NumpadLeft} instead of #{Left}.
I uninstalled it to test it without your UIAccess tip and it worked as well. So, probably in this case UIAccess is not necessary.
Thanks again.

Comment: Me too. Really strange, though, that the help suggests no difference between them. Maybe it's because *normally* there's none.